# PHP - Getting a sub-string from a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, substring

I have a string as

```
$line = "Name=johnGender=M";
```

How to make a string called `$name` that will have a value stored as `john`.
How to extract a sub-string which is enclosed between `=` and `G` in the string $line.

OR grab a sub-string of 4 characters from the first encounter of `=` (this will work for me).

What if `$line=array("Name=john&Gender=M",Name=carl&Gender=M",);` And I wanted to put them in an array `$name` So that `$name=array("john", "carl");`

Comment: There's no actual separator between each field? such as `$line = "Name=john&Gender=M";` This seems to me like it would be very problematic.

Comment: What if $line=array("Name=john&Gender=M",Name=carl&Gender=M",); And I wanted to put them in an array $name So that $name=array("john", "carl"); <both contain same number of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the following would work for you.

```
$name = array();
foreach($line as $elem)
    array_push($name,substr(explode("=",$elem)[1],0,4));
```

So you can access it as `$name[0],$name[1],...`

Better try to have the input syntax as

```
$line = array("Name=john&Gender=M","Name=raja&Gender=M");
parse_str($line);
```

So you can use the built-in function `parse_str()`.

Now  `$Name[0]` contains **john** and `$Name[1]` contains **raja**.

Comment: What if $line=array("Name=john&Gender=M",Name=carl&Gender=M",);
And I wanted to put them in an array $name
So that $name=array("john", "carl"); <both contain same number of characters.

Comment: I have never used `foreach();` before would you write me a code. Including my above written code.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we dont know the length of the name. Say,
`$line = "Name=SaifUrRehmanGender=M";`

Use strpos() to get the index of "Gender"

> The strpos() function finds the position of the first occurrence of a string inside another string.

For your case:
`$name = substr($line,5,strpos($line,"Gender")-5);` will do :)

Output: `SaifUrRehman`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$line = "Name=johnGender=M";
//explode the string by '='
$info = explode('=', $line);
//then you have in $info[1] this string: johnGender
// and you get the first 4 characters in $name
$name = substr($info[1], 0, 4);

echo $name;

?>
```

Output:

> john

```
<?php

$line = array("Name=john&Gender=M","Name=carl&Gender=M");

$array = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($line); $i++) {
  $info = explode('=', $line[$i]);
  $name = explode('&', $info[1]);
  $array[] = $name[0];
}   

foreach($array as $name) {
    echo $name . "<br>\n";
}   

?>
```

Output:

> john
>
> carl

Comment: What if $line=array("Name=john&Gender=M",Name=carl&Gender=M",); And I wanted to put them in an array $name So that $name=array("john", "carl"); <both contain same number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function strinbetween($inputstring, $start, $end){
    $inputstring = " ".$inputstring;
    $ini = strpos($inputstring,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($inputstring,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($inputstring,$ini,$len);
}
```

Call the above function and pass the string, starting string and ending string

```
$line = "Name=johnGender=M";
$parsed = strinbetween($line,'=','G');
echo $parsed;
```

So here it will return `john`

Comment: What if $line=array("Name=john&Gender=M",Name=carl&Gender=M",); And I wanted to put them in an array $name So that $name=array("john", "carl"); <both contain same number of characters.